# ValueError: objects are not aligned using curve_fit and a matrix model

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I'm trying to fit the parameters of a transition probability matrix (a Leslie model in ecology). My function for the Leslie model is:

```
def leslie(x, f3, p0, p1, p2):
    Alist = [[0, 0, 0, f3], [p0, 0, 0, 0], [0, p1, 0, 0], [0, 0, p2, 0]]
    A = np.array(Alist)
    X = np.array(x).T
    return list(np.dot(A, X))
```

I'm trying to use `scipy`'s `curve_fit` with data of x and y values, where each value is a list of 4 measurements (x is year 1 and y is year 2 data). The first couple of lines of data look like this:

```
                             ABUNDY1                            ABUNDY2
0  [516.819166236, 10.0, 15.0, 40.0]     [3756.96048518, 2.0, 1.0, 1.0]
1  [16454.2226677, 25.0, 60.0, 50.0]  [23511.7855689, 50.0, 35.0, 12.0]
2     [14415.487266, 20.0, 8.0, 2.0]    [248.215580071, 30.0, 2.0, 3.0]
3     [2477.19325817, 5.0, 5.0, 2.0]    [321.324366027, 10.0, 7.0, 4.0]
4  [43.2506601374, 15.0, 20.0, 10.0]   [1651.83654693, 15.0, 10.0, 4.0]
```

I'm calling:

```
res = scipy.optimize.curve_fit(leslie, data.ABUNDY1, data.ABUNDY2)
```

I get `ValueError: objects not aligned`. The `leslie` function I wrote seems to be working without a problem when I try it outside of curve fitting. I assume my issue is array dimensions not being correctly matching, but I'm having trouble seeing the error.

Comment: are the fields in `ABUNDY1` and `ABUNDY2` the parameters `f3, p0, p1, p2`? These should be passed to `curve_fit` as the `p0` argument (initial guess). Your function `leslie` should return a single float value, not a list, your must think what would be the `xdata` and `ydata` inputs of `curve_fit` ([see the documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.13.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html) for more details)